# Converting Bytes from SQL Server Database to Image in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

When trying to convert Bytes in my database to an Image to display, when reaching this line:

```
Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

The code will jump to a form load in a different form. Any reason why this would be?

Rest of code:

```
    private void dataGridView2_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //try
        //{


            if (dataGridView2.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
            {
                int selectrowindex = dataGridView2.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
                DataGridViewRow selectrow = dataGridView2.Rows[selectrowindex];

                productID = Convert.ToString(selectrow.Cells[0].Value);
                productName.Text = Convert.ToString(selectrow.Cells[1].Value);
                productDetails.Text = ("Desc: " + Convert.ToString(selectrow.Cells[2].Value));
                productPrice.Text = (Convert.ToString(selectrow.Cells[4].Value));
                productStock.Text = Convert.ToString(selectrow.Cells[5].Value);

                db_connection();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Image FROM PRODUCTS WHERE ProductID = @ProductID", connect);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ProductID", productID);

                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                reader.Read();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    byte[] img = (byte[])(reader[0]);
                    if (img == null)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Theres no image");
                        productPictureDisplay.Image = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);
                        Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);
                        productPictureDisplay.Image = image;
                    }
                }

                connect.Close();

            }
    }
```

Comment: write try...catch there may be error ..but code seems ok to me

Comment: Could it be the bytes in my DB that are off?

Comment: not sure about db part but seems ok

Comment: if you are getting data here  byte[] img = (byte[])(reader[0]);, that db is ok

Comment: Yeah it doesn't return null which means there's something there. But maybe what its reading isn't translatable to an image

Comment: can try below code and try to check you are getting any error or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try as below , and start making use of `using` in your code so things get dispose by it (you connection object, memory stream)

```
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    try
    {
       var ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);;
          return Image.FromStream(ms);
     }
    catch(Exception ex)
    { console.WriteLine(ex.Tostring()); }
    return returnImage;
}
```

Comment: Just returning null

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't close the stream, it needs to remain open for the lifetime of the image.

Comment: @DerrickMoeller it need to be closed...sems like your byte array is corrupted ...what are you getting in exception ???

Comment: @PranayRana I'm not the OP, I'm not getting an exception but you can't close the stream.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @DerrickMoeller - seems like i am wrong update my answer code ..thanks for pointing it out ... will try this thing at my end